# Stop parent div onclick function to child element say anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I want to stop onclick function of Parent div say class="service-box-inner" for my child element anchor tag say class="caps_link", but issue i am facing is when i click 'perform a demo' it first opens popup and then opens google page, i want to stop controls on opening of popup but it leads to page google 
**HTML Markup**

```
<div class="service-box-inner" onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'">
    <img class="service-icon" src="../images/icons/service-icon-1.png" alt="ehr" />
    <small class="service-description">Some Meaningful Use .</small>
    <a href="#" data-target="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal" class="caps_link" onclick="function abc(event);">perform a demo</a>
</div>
```

Here is my JQuery code

```
function abc(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `onclick` attribute is attempting to define a function, not call one. Try this:

```
<a href="#" data-target="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal" class="caps_link" onclick="abc(event);">perform a demo</a>
```

Also note that the method you're using is not jQuery and is outdated. To utilise jQuery, try this:

```
<a href="#" data-target="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal" class="caps_link">perform a demo</a>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('a.caps_link').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Rory i have up voted you for answering, but this is not helping the cause.Since it has stopped opening #myModal1
but cheers, i have done it otherwise(using If statement) :) thank you anyways